# selecting a value from df during ddply summarise

Tags: r, plyr

I want to use `ddply` and `summarise` to get the monthly medians for several years of data. I can do this successfully. However, I would also like to have a column with the value for one year of the data. I know other ways to add this, but would like to do it within the `ddply` line. Data is at the bottom.

The first row of the result would look like this if median for all years is 16 and the value for 2018 is 30:

```
Month Median 2018
 
Apr   16.0   30
```

Here is what I have tried:
This works as expected:

```r
Summary<-ddply(df, ~Month, summarise, Median = median(Value))
Summary
```

When I try to add the single year value I can't seem to think of a way to do it:

```r
Summary<-ddply(df, ~Month, summarise, Median = median(Value), SingleYearValue = which(df[,"Year"]==2018));Summary

df<-structure(list(Month = c("Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
                             "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
                             "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", 
                             "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Aug", "Aug", 
                             "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", 
                             "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", 
                             "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", 
                             "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", 
                             "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Dec", "Feb", "Feb", 
                             "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
                             "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", 
                             "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
                             "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
                             "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
                             "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", 
                             "Jul", "Jul", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
                             "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
                             "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", 
                             "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Mar", "Mar", 
                             "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", 
                             "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "May", "May", "May", 
                             "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", 
                             "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", 
                             "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", "May", 
                             "May", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", 
                             "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", 
                             "Nov", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
                             "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
                             "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
                             "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
                             "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
                             "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
                             "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
                             "Sep"), Year = c("1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", 
                                              "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2002", 
                                              "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
                                              "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
                                              "2019", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", 
                                              "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2001", "2002", 
                                              "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
                                              "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
                                              "2019", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", 
                                              "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1960", "1961", 
                                              "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", 
                                              "1970", "1971", "1972", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", 
                                              "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", 
                                              "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", 
                                              "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2001", "2002", "2003", 
                                              "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
                                              "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
                                              "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", 
                                              "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2001", "2002", "2003", 
                                              "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
                                              "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
                                              "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", 
                                              "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
                                              "2019", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", 
                                              "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2002", "2003", 
                                              "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
                                              "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
                                              "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", 
                                              "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "2005", "2015", "2016", 
                                              "2017", "2018", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", 
                                              "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "2001", 
                                              "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2010", 
                                              "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
                                              "2019", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966", 
                                              "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "2001", "2002", 
                                              "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", 
                                              "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
                                              "2019"), Value = 1:295), row.names = c(NA, -295L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `plyr` has been retired. Try to use `dplyr` instead. I am not clear about how you want to show the final output. Will you have a new column for each year?

Comment: @Ronak Shah I am just looking for the value for the year I select. In other words, I would like to be able to put 2018 in the code and have it return a column with the 2018 values (one for each month that is summarized). Then, if I wanted I could switch 2018 to 2019 and run the code again so that I would have a column with the 2019 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to do this all in `plyr`, use the `plyr::join`

```
plyr::join(Summary, subset(df, Year == 2018, select = -Year))
#    Month Median Value
#1    Apr   16.0    30
#2    Aug   47.5    62
#3    Dec   70.0    NA
#4    Feb   83.0    NA
#5    Jan   96.0    NA
#6    Jul  118.5   133
#7    Jun  150.5   165
#8    Mar  175.0   182
#9    May  199.0   213
#10   Nov  223.5   232
#11   Oct  248.0   262
#12   Sep  279.5   294
```

---

Or if we want to do this within `ddply`

```
plyr::ddply(df, ~ Month, summarise, Median = median(Value),
        `2018` = Value[Year == 2018][1])
#   Month Median 2018
#1    Apr   16.0   30
#2    Aug   47.5   62
#3    Dec   70.0   NA
#4    Feb   83.0   NA
#5    Jan   96.0   NA
#6    Jul  118.5  133
#7    Jun  150.5  165
#8    Mar  175.0  182
#9    May  199.0  213
#10   Nov  223.5  232
#11   Oct  248.0  262
#12   Sep  279.5  294
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `subset` a particular years value and then `merge` :

```
year = 2018
data <- subset(df, Year == year, select = -Year)
names(data)[names(data) == 'Value'] <- year
merge(Summary, data, by = 'Month', all.x = TRUE)

#   Month Median 2018
#1    Apr   16.0   30
#2    Aug   47.5   62
#3    Dec   70.0   NA
#4    Feb   83.0   NA
#5    Jan   96.0   NA
#6    Jul  118.5  133
#7    Jun  150.5  165
#8    Mar  175.0  182
#9    May  199.0  213
#10   Nov  223.5  232
#11   Oct  248.0  262
#12   Sep  279.5  294
```

Comment: This is exactly the output that I want. I would still like to find a way to do it within the `plyr` code, but this will probably have to do for know. `plyr` is retired anyways as you mentioned. I think, I am just having a hard time giving up on it because I have tried to do it many times over the past few years, and it drives me crazy that I a haven't found a way.